# D3 - Fisheye for Sunburst Chart

Tags: d3.js, fisheye, sunburst-diagram

I am trying to implement Fisheye for Sunburst chart. I couldn't make it work. I tried something similar to the below example.

http://jsfiddle.net/g88S7/

```
    svg.on("mousemove", function() {
    fisheye.focus(d3.mouse(this));
});
```

Can someone tell me if I am missing something?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how it didn't work and show us your code?

Comment: I think this is not an easy proposition. The Fisheye implementation is expecting x,y coords as input. So, one would have to deconstruct the various x,y coords in the path description attribute (d), feed them to the Fisheye (no pun intended), and then re-construct the path description attribute with the distorted coords. For reference, see the [SVG documentation for paths](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html). Having said all that, I would be very interested in @AmeliaBR's take on this.